# Attaching To Work Item With Checkbox

Tags: visual-studio-2013

We recently upgraded our TFS 2010 to TFS 2013. I like most of the changes, but some of them not so much. **Did Microsoft really took away the feature that was in TFS 2010 where one could attach to an work item by checking a checkbox next to the work item?** The way I currently do in TFS 2013 is, before checking in I run my TFS query, remember the work item number, then do 'Add By Id' or something like that, type the ID and enter. It might not seem big deal to many, but I absolutely do not like this. Is there a way to get those checkboxes next to the work item back? If not, is there a better way to do that process?

Comment: No, I haven't. So do I just write to Microsoft asking this same question? I didn't know I could do that... Wouldn't that be a  lengthy process though? I searched a couple of variation of this question online, but looks like it's just me and my coworker with this complaint. I feel like there is an easier way to do the task that I am not aware of yet.

Comment: have you written to a relevant Microsoft forum? Lodged a connect item? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=tfsgeneral

Comment: Just posted to the MS Forums as well. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e002c21c-556c-4e63-88b9-33a76b12811d/tfs-2013-attaching-to-work-item-with-checkbox?forum=tfsgeneral

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks. Got it. Will keep that in mind moving forward.

Answer (score 2):

It has changed a little but I guess the closest experience is to create a personal query or add a shared query to your favourites.

In the Pending Changes Window under Related Work Items click the Queries drop down and select the relevant query.

The results will open in the main window and you can drag and drop a work item into the Related Work Items section which will link it to your changeset.

If you have VS Premium or Ultimate then you can use the My Work window in Team Explorer which will list your assigned work items in the Available Work Items section and you can just drag them into In Progress Work.

Comment: I did realize of that drag and drop feature, but that is still not exactly what I wanted. May be it is just a matter of time of getting used this style. I like the fact that it lets you drag multiple work items, that is certainly more helpful than typing in WorkItemID. Thanks and +1 for helping me discover that. Still wish I could do without having to reach for the mouse.